# Obtaining access token when User Assigned Identity is enabled

Tags: azure-functions, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to access Azure Function through azure portal using managed identity. Below line of code works well if I use system assigned identity.

```
  [FunctionName("FunctionDemo")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req,
ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Starting to get accessToken through client id");
    string accessToken = await azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/")
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

However, same code throws exception when I switch to user assigned identity.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the user-assigned identity, you need to specify the `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` environment variable in your function like below, then the `AzureServiceTokenProvider` will use the user-assigned identity to get token.

```
RunAs=App;AppId={ClientId of user-assigned identity}
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/service-to-service-authentication#connection-string-support

[image]